# Array is gone after refreshing page, even though I use LocalStorage?

Tags: angular, typescript, local-storage

I call this add method in my template and I can add new objects into the eintraege-array. In the internet, it says that the LocalStorage is used that when I refresh the page, all my changes are being stored. But it doesn't. Below is the add method, which is called in a component and the add method calls another saveData method, which is coming from one of the LocalStorage-Methods.
Please tell me, if you need more information. Hope this is enough

```
eintraege: Eintrag[] = [];
  
  add(beschreibung: string, faelligkeitsdatum: string) {

      var eintrag: Eintrag = {
        beschreibung: '',
        faelligkeitsdatum: '',
        erledigt: false,
      };

      eintrag.beschreibung = beschreibung;
      eintrag.faelligkeitsdatum = faelligkeitsdatum;
      eintrag.erledigt = false;

      this.eintraege.unshift(eintrag);

      this.eintragService.saveData('token', JSON.stringify(this.eintraege))
```

my service, which uses LocalStorage:

```
public saveData(key: string, value: string) {
    localStorage.setItem('token', value);
  }
```

EDIT:
I do use the getItem-Method:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getEintraege();
  }
getEintraege(): void {
    this.eintragService.getData('token')
  }
```

and in my service it looks like this:

```
 public getData(key: string) {
    return localStorage.getItem(key)
  }
```

But as soon as I refresh the page, everything is gone.

Comment: It looks like you don't *retrieve* the data from localStorage?

Comment: Please take a look at the edits

Comment: You don't *do* anything with the retrieved data.

Comment: This means, I have to put the data into my array eintraege via:
getEintraege(): void {
    this.eintraege = this.eintragService.getData('token')
  }
But I can't convert a String to an Object "Eintrag", which I am getting with the method "getData"

Comment: Then use the opposite of JSON.stringify, which is [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you supposed to have something like that in your component

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.eintraege = localStorage.getItem('token')
}
```

Comment: yes I do have exactly that. it is showing me the objects I add, BUT LocalStorage is not saving them when I refresh the page.

Comment: Do you check the `localStorage` itself? you can find it under application tab in the developer tools